# When to use Async.RunSynchronously, Async.map or let

Tags: f#

Consider these 3 versions

```ml
async {
  return! retrieved =
             client
             |> get tagIdOfQid None
             |> Async.Catch
             |> Async.map (function
                  | Choice1Of2 doc ->
                      doc
                      |> mapDoc
                      |> function
                      | IdOfQ d -> d
                      | _ -> defaultTagIdOfQ
                  | _ -> defaultTagIdOfQ)
}
```

```ml
async {
  return retrieved =
             client
             |> get tagIdOfQid None
             |> Async.Catch
             |> Async.RunSynchronously 
             |> function
                  | Choice1Of2 doc ->
                      doc
                      |> mapDoc
                      |> function
                      | IdOfQ d -> d
                      | _ -> defaultTagIdOfQ
                  | _ -> defaultTagIdOfQ)
}
```

```ml
async {
  let! retrieved =
             client
             |> get tagIdOfQid None
             |> Async.Catch
   
   return! retrieved
           |> function
           | Choice1Of2 doc ->
              doc
              |> mapDoc
              |> function
              | IdOfQ d -> d
              | _ -> defaultTagIdOfQ
           | _ -> defaultTagIdOfQ
}
```

I want to pipe the result of the `get` to another computation, I can use `Async.map`, `Async.RunSynchronously` or add multiple `let!` bindings.

I see them all as valid alternatives for doing the same, without any differences, but maybe I'm wrong and they are doing slightly different things.

Is there any tradeoff between `Async.map`, `Async.RunSynchronously` and `let!`?

Answer (score 3):

The key difference is that if you use `Async.RunSynchronously`, even if this is inside another `async` workflow, this will block a thread when you run it. Using `Async.map` will not block and multiple `let!` is the same in this respect.

So, I would avoid using `Async.RunSynchronously`. As to what else to do, this is a style preference.

Using `async { return! e }` does not make sense, because it means exactly the same as just `e`, so you can simplify the first approach. I also replaced the confusing (to me at least) inner pipe with ordinary `match`:

```
client
|> get tagIdOfQid None
|> Async.Catch
|> Async.map (function
    | Choice1Of2 doc ->
        match mapDoc doc with 
        | IdOfQ d -> d
        | _ -> defaultTagIdOfQ
    | _ -> defaultTagIdOfQ)
```

In the second approach, I would also remove some of the pipelines, because I find them hard to follow. If you are inside `async` you can also use ordinary `try ... with` instead of `Async.Catch`:

```
async {
  try 
    let! doc = get tagIdOfQid None client
    match mapDoc doc with 
    | IdOfQ d -> return d
    | _ -> return defaultTagIdOfQ
   with _ -> return defaultTagIdOfQ 
}
```

If I was writing this, I would go with the latter - mainly because it is very easy to read & understand what is going on.